# How can I generate a pdf using CakePhp v3.x

Tags: cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I'm using `CakePHP` v3.x, how can I generate a PDF file?

There is the possibility to generate an "only for download" or "only for print" file? (which doesn't need to be saved on server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I generate a pdf using CakePhp v3.x?

Here's a plugin for this: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf